# How do I make my elements in place when I resize the page?

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, it looks perfectly fine, but when I drag the page down or to the right, there will be a lot of extra white spaces at the top as well as the right side of the page which makes it just looks unnatural. Basically I want everything to fit withing the page regardless of how much I drag it. Is there a simple solution to fix this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Zetta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82c7176f2a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="background-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460602594182-8568137446ce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80">
  <img class="profile-image" src="https://gamerheadquarters.com/hub/avatar/fallout76tshirt.jpg" alt="profile picture">
    <figcaption class="name">JOHN <span>JOHNSON</span></figcaption>
  <div class="header-background">
  </div>
  <hr>

  <header>
    <nav class="header-links">
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <nav class="footer-side-links">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/parham-javadi/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/papar24/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/pjfooeve09" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>
</head>
```

CSS

```
.background-img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  height: 830px;
  width: 1270px;
  bottom: 1px;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  top: 250px;
  border: 7px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.profile-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.name span {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.name {
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top: 280px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}

.header-background {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: #3d3d5c;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 17.9rem;
}

.header-links a {
  color: #cccfc2;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-links {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 200px;

}

.header-links a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.footer-side-links a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.footer-side-links a:hover {
  color: orange
}

.footer-side-links {
  left: 3rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout structure is very bad !

- No proper wrapper or main container
- header shouldnt be placed next to footer
- using CSS positions for organising elements and changing the top down hiearchy using absolute and fixed positions is not a good design pattern
- Using px width and height for images won't make it responsive ! use relative units like % or vw/vh

Go through basic html css tutorials ! Start with things like box model .

Every single element on a webpage is a rectangle with width height margin border . To make an element strech and fit accordingly when you resize you use [media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) . Media queries decide how elements look in different screens like Desktop, tablet and mobile etc..

[this](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/opening-the-box-model/) article is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inspection tool on the browser to check what elements are creating blanks and edit them. Anyway, i don't know how the project is planned, but maybe you should try set the styles of elements with non static sizes, set the background to the body with the 'background' property instead a absolute positioned div, among other things.